# Using keystrokes in Linux Terminal

Tags: gnu-screen

How I can simulate keyboard input, something like CTRL+A+D, in linux terminal? Is there any command for this?

Reason I'm asking this is that I need some other way to detach from my screen session than to use CTRL+A+D

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why can't you type Ctrl+A D? I presume you want to do something programmatically, but where is that program running? Inside the screen session? Or outside, and if so how does it know which screen session to target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html)

The official page seems to be down right now, so I am linking to the manpage.

To issue <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>, just use

`xdotool key 'ctrl+a+d'`